# PECL solr not loading due to undefined symbol: curl_easy_getinfo

Tags: php, solr, pecl

I'm trying to load the PECL solr extension.  I have tried installed it using "pecl install solr" and by downloading and using "phpize/configure/make".  In both cases, the extension installs with no errors, but after an apache restart (or when running php on the command line) this error message is always emitted:

```
PHP Warning: Unable to load dynamic library /usr/lib64/php/modules/solr.so
 - /usr/lib64/php/modules/solr.so: undefined symbol:
 curl_easy_getinfo in Unknown on line 0
```

I checked and it appears that the created solr.so object does NOT know about /usr/lib64/libcurl.so, even though I specified LDFLAGS -L/usr/lib64 (though I should not need to):

```
 # ldd modules/solr.so
       linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd5af8000)
       libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fac573c0000)
       /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000034bc000000)
```

I am using an out-of-the-box Fedora 15 installation.  I have installed many other PECL extensions with no issue.  Why is this so hard, and more importantly, how can I fix it?!?

I am using FC15, PHP 5.3.8, curl 7.21.3.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: is the plug in?  Or, does /usr/lib64/php/modules/solr.so really exists and has the right permissions?

Comment: I get a similar message when running "make test" about the locally-built solr.so so I don't think that's relevant.  But yes, it exists and has the same permissions as the other objects.  What do you mean by "is the plug in"?

Comment: "Is the plug in"..a Jocj, the first question a HD asks a user who complains about his computer not working. First we clear the most obvious reasons...
Now, did you upgrade you PHP lately, is your phpize the correct version?

Comment: This is an out-of-the-box Fedora Core 15 installation, patched to whatever the software updator patched it to.  I would assume that phpize is the correct version, but how does one check?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out what the problem was either, as I was able to compile via pecl (phpize/configure/make/make install) on Fedora 16 just fine.

First make sure you got libc compat installed:

```
compat-glibc.i386 : Compatibility C library
compat-glibc.x86_64 : Compatibility C library
compat-glibc-headers.x86_64 : Header files for development using standard C
```

Once I installed the packages above, I configured/make/make install and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was:
Edit:
/etc/php.d/json.ini
and add extension=solr.so this causes loading solr extension after json extension, avoiding json library missing.

Ej json.ini:

; Enable json extension module
extension=json.so
extension=solr.so

Answer (score 0):

That means that it needs curl
Install the dependencies like the following:

```
sudo yum install libxml2-devel curl curl-devel php-curl
```

Answer (score -2):

I faced a similar problem and found a solution to work.

To fix this , just create a file called /etc/php.d/solr.so and add its content as :

```
;Enable the solr php extension
extension=solr.so
```

and then just reload your web server. It should work now.