# how to instal php-solr-client on aws beanstalk with pecl

Tags: php, solr, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i have installed a beanstalk server on amazon aws. i also have a different instance running SOLR server.

in my php scripts i use this module: http://php.net/manual/en/solrclient.adddocument.php
to query the SOLR database.

to install it on beanstalk, i login into its ec2 instance, (ec2-user).
this module uses pecl

in the ec2 shell:

```
sudo pecl install -n solr
```

once done, pecl will add `extension = solr.so` to php.ini

from this point, when i run php scripts i recive:

`PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/solr.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/solr.so: undefined symbol: curl_easy_getinfo in Unknown on line 0`

i found a very few other posts about this issue, but most gave up or gave incomplete/unclear solutions.

Comment: How about listing the specific other [candidate duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8157709/168868) and why their solutions did not work for you?  The error message is pretty darn clear - something in your curl libraries is broken or missing.

Comment: did pecl add the line to php.ini or is it just supposed to?

Comment: Charles - because the other posts didnt solve the error, why would we follow dead links...,also nothing was missing...

Comment: toby - pecl does add a line to php.ini, which was part of the problem, but i didnt know that at the time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how to install solr php client on aws beanstalk - 
(this php client - http://php.net/manual/en/solrclient.construct.php)

1. assumming you have beanstalk server up and running

   - login into ec2 instance created by beanstalk
2. sudo pecl install -n solr -> (add /usr/lib as a location folder when prompt for xmlcurl,libcur while installing via pecl)
3. delete “extension=solr.so” from php.ini  -> (found in root/etc)
4. add file "solr.ini" with one line = (put in root/etc/php.d)
5. sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart -> restart the server

   - make sure solr server ports 8443 : 8983 are open for beanstalk.
6. profit.
7. now that this is running, if you are running this to connect to solr 4.0 server you will notice that it will not work correctly (commit -> waitflush arg was removed in 4.0 but still exists on the client)
8. no profit for me...

Answer (score 0):

Yaron's reply Didnt work for me.

However the below did.

i simply added

```
extension=curl.so
extension=json.so
extension=solr.so
```

at the end of **php.ini**
and it worked without any issues.

Note:
i am using php 5.5.12